# How can i achieve Bokeh effect with custom camera in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, multi-camera-api

I need to generate Bokeh effect with the android custom camera. 
I am using a dual-camera device. But unable to find any option to take the picture and do Image segmentation.

I had a look at some library also and found https://github.com/RedApparat/FaceDetector library. If I could focus an object and blur rest of background then also it will be working for me.

Is there any hint how device with dual lens works?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this answer that seems a bit similar to what you wanted , depth information from the dual cameras: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421329/get-depth-from-dual-camera-android-smartphone

Comment: @florentteppe sorry but it didn't helped. is there any hint how device with dual lens  working?