# How to retrieve all the dual or triple camera specifications programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I used to retrieve all the specifications of Rear and Front Camera details as below.

```
Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
Camera camera = Camera.open(i);
Camera.Parameters cameraParams = camera.getParameters();
```

After the release of new Dual and triple camera mobiles. I am not able to retrieve all the 3 camera's details separately. By passing i = 0 or 1 will retrieve the details of the rear and front camera. There is no 3rd value for the `i`. Did anyone come across such an issue, and how you handled that?

Comment: on what mobile are you testing this?

Comment: This is impossible by design in most cases, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46205821/192373. But https://github.com/autosquid/dualcamera shows that at least some LG devices let you do this.

Comment: @D.'s i tested in latest Mi mobiles with dual camera